# replacing single driver within windows XP SP2

Tags: windows, windows-xp, drivers, modem

Prestory: I would like to connect and use [Huawei E3372](https://modem.co.uk/product/huawei-e3372/) modem with Windows XP SP2. However, according to diagnostics and system requirements, it appears that it requires at least XP SP3 to work.

I have investigated a bit more and found out that this device is properly recognized, but can't be initialized. I suspect the reason is that XP SP3 has a newer version of mobile internet sharing driver.

Now, the actual question. Does anyone know if it possible to replace single driver on XP SP2 from XP SP3 instance? Will system do repair after this?

Comment: What is preventing you from upgrading to SP3? And, obligatory reminder that any computer running Windows XP that is connected to the internet is going to be highly insecure.

Comment: I have specific software which doesn't run on XP SP3+, therefore I can't upgrade. I am aware of security risks though

Comment: "Does anyone know if it possible to replace single driver on XP SP2 from XP SP3 instance? Will system do repair after this?" I would try it, what could that hurt, and this would answer your own question. Replacing system files will have to be done offline as XP has resource protection that keeps critical files from being tampered with while booted into XP.